# MS SQL Selecting tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005

I have database `A , A_Archive`. I have T table in `A` and also `A_Archive`(same structure)
Can I do a select (or even create a view ) to see somthing like this:

```
.
.
.
A_Archive records
.
.
.
A records
```

and how?

Thanks

Comment: Are `A` and `A_Archive` databases? And `T` is the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using fully qualified names, like:

```
SELECT * FROM A_Archive.dbo.T
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM A.dbo.T
```

depending on whether `dbo` is the correct scheme. Also you need to make sure the user excuting the select does have the necessary rights on both databases.

Answer (score 1):

If the both databases are on the same server you can simply write this query

```
SELECT * FROM [DatabaseName].dbo.[tableName]
  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [AnotherDatabaseName].dbo.[AnothertableName]
```

But if these two databases are on different servers you need to consider `sp_addlinkedserver` to create a server link. read more from this **[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)**

Hope it will help

Comment: is there any limit unioning tables? My A database is full(10GB; bunch of measurments). I create A_Archive and also a view in A_archive to see continuously the T table. I know only 255 tables can be put into a view. Limitations like View can only have N number of rows?

Comment: No. There's no limit to the number of records returned. If there were you'd not be able to get all the data from a large table if you really need it.